# What is the Ace's namesake?

Tags: learning

The other face-cards are pretty obvious.

King is a king, Queen is a queen, Jack is a prince

What about ace?

Comment: Jack is a prince? Is that a thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We got "Ace" from the French "as", which got it from the Latin "as", meaning something like "unit" or "whole". The term was applied first to the one-spot side of a die, and only later to cards.